# Tailwind: color children links red

Tags: tailwind-css, tailwind-ui

I've got some DOM:

```
<div>
  <p>
    <a>ham</a>
  </p>
</div>
```

I want to add a class attribute to the DIV to turn all the children a tags red. I know I can do `<div class="[&>p>a]:text-red-500">` but the a tags can be at any arbitrary depth within the `<div>`. Anyone know the syntax to make the links red?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could consider using a selector in the arbitrary variant that does not have any direct descendent operators:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.3.2"></script>

<div class="[&_a]:text-red-500">
  <p>
    <a>ham</a>
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! Do you know where in the docs this is discussed?

Comment: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/hover-focus-and-other-states#using-arbitrary-variants